# Laravel adds few lines of code before every asset I load from the public folder, which corrupts the assets ( like images )

Tags: laravel, assets, laravel-blade

Long time lurking and learning from other people's troubles, first time asking. I'm a beginner when it comes to coding (few months of learning frontend stuff and a bit of PHP) that is trying out the Laravel framework with Blade Templates.

Problem:

I put most of my static assets ( like my css files, images and some jquery plugins I use ) in the public folder so that they are accessible with simple paths - and they indeed are (as inspecting in browser shows, I use the built in artisan serve command to make a local host), however I noticed that images and scripts aren't working - because they get corrupted by a couple of lines of data which gets inserted at the top of every file. When I open the  image in an editor that was uploaded this way this is what I found:

```
�HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/jpeg 
Content-Length: 260570
```

(followed by standard image gibberish)

And for the scripts:

```
�HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 58701
```

This makes the images and js scripts unusable. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or why this is happening?

Thank you in advance. I'm using the newest Laravel version 5.4.16 installed through Composer on Windows 7.

webpack.mix.js file is the standard code that comes with a fresh installation:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

webpack.config file from the public folder is here:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

edit:
I tried the same project on another computer, and everything works normally there ... I'm not sure what's up, it's also Windows 7 but not everything is the same. PHP version I tied to the Composer for example was different. I wish I knew what exactly caused this issue.

Comment: laravel shouldn't modify any of your files, how are you referencing them in you blade templates?

Comment: I'm just using standard HTML markup, like so: <img src="img/campaignImage.jpg"> , with the image being stored in public/img folder of the Laravel project. I tried with the asset() method as was suggested in some similar SO questions, but the results were the same.

Comment: Can you post your `webpack.mix.js` and `webpack.config.js` files?

Comment: webpack.mix.js is here:

const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');


which should be the default that came with laravel. I couldn't find a webpack.config.js. A quick google search told me this file might not exist until you decide to make changes to the default setting

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on another computer, and everything works normally ( which is also on windows 7 ). Why it is bugged here ... god knows. Maybe the CL Version of PHP I was using when I installed the composer wasn't good ( I tied it to 7.0.something version I got from MAMP here, where it was bugged, and on my other version I tied it to a WAMP 5.something PHP ).

It remains a mystery what exactly caused the issue, but at least I know how to bypass it now.